# Temporary Shiny Loading error: filter_impl

Tags: r, shiny

I'm getting "Error in filter_impl: Result must have length 5, not 0" when I launch the Shiny app. This happens locally and when hosted. The error is only temporary -- it goes away after a half of a second. And it doesn't seem to be a problem for the functioning of the app. But it is annoying to see the error message! Any ideas how to resolve this?

Here is a reproducible example (pared down from a longer script):

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
require(shiny)

##Section 1 ____________________________________________________
#load your data or create a data table as follows:
schools <- structure(list(school_name = c("Berkeley Terrace", "Grove Street School", 
                               "Madison At Chancellor South", "Mt. Vernon Avenue School", "Thurgood Marshall School"
), district_name = c("Irvington Township", "Irvington Township", 
                     "Irvington Township", "Irvington Township", "Irvington Township"
), Percent_Black_Students = c(0.755364806866953, 0.903292181069959, 
                              0.813953488372093, 0.857913669064748, 0.824644549763033), Percent_Black_Teachers = c(1, 
                                                                                                                   1, 1, 1, 1), Percent_Latinx_Students = c(0.233905579399142, 0.088477366255144, 
                                                                                                                                                            0.176079734219269, 0.12589928057554, 0.163507109004739), Percent_Latinx_Teachers = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0), Percent_White_Students = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00539568345323741, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0023696682464455), Percent_White_Teachers = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

##Section 2 ____________________________________________________
#set up the user interface
ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage( #allows layout to fill browser window
    titlePanel("Why does the error flash and then go away?"),
    sidebarPanel( #designates location of following items
      htmlOutput("school_selector")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1") #put plot item in main area

      # Output: HTML table with requested number of observations ----
      # tableOutput("view")

    )
  ) )


##Section 3 ____________________________________________________
#server controls what is displayed by the user interface
server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$school_selector = renderUI({#creates County select box object called in ui

    data_available <- schools
    #creates a reactive list of available x based on the y selection made

    selectInput(inputId = "school", #name of input
                label = "School:", #label displayed in ui
                choices = unique(data_available), #calls list of available counties
                selected = "Madison At Chancellor South")
  })


  output$plot1 = renderPlot({ #creates a the plot to go in the mainPanel


    focal.school <- schools %>% filter(school_name == input$school)

  ggplot(focal.school, aes(x=input$school, y=Percent_Black_Students)) +
    geom_point()
  })

})#close the shinyServer


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also: I've set up the input selection to cascade into other input selectors in the main app. That is, first choose district, then that will populate a dropdown with schools...and at that point the user will choose a school, etc.

Comment: Side point: do not use `require` here, because if the package is not installed, the app will continue without failure and you will not know it until something doesn't work as expected. (Refs: https://yihui.name/en/2014/07/library-vs-require/ and http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#search-path.)

Comment: But I get the same error when I try `filter(schools, school_name==character(0))`, suggesting that your `input$school` is empty. You might want to add `req(input$school)` to the beginning of your `renderPlot` block, as it will prevent attempting a plot until there is something "truthy" about it (essentially, truthy is not-null, not-empty, not-false). See `?isTruthy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when the app starts, it takes some time to process your `renderUI()` function. During this time, `input$school` is empty and thus the error. You can correct this using `validate()` and `need()`. Read [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) for learning more about validate and general error handling in shiny. Corrected code:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
require(shiny)

##Section 1 ____________________________________________________
#load your data or create a data table as follows:
schools <- structure(list(school_name = c("Berkeley Terrace", "Grove Street School", 
                                          "Madison At Chancellor South", "Mt. Vernon Avenue School", "Thurgood Marshall School"
), district_name = c("Irvington Township", "Irvington Township", 
                     "Irvington Township", "Irvington Township", "Irvington Township"
), Percent_Black_Students = c(0.755364806866953, 0.903292181069959, 
                              0.813953488372093, 0.857913669064748, 0.824644549763033), Percent_Black_Teachers = c(1, 
                                                                                                                   1, 1, 1, 1), Percent_Latinx_Students = c(0.233905579399142, 0.088477366255144, 
                                                                                                                                                            0.176079734219269, 0.12589928057554, 0.163507109004739), Percent_Latinx_Teachers = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0, 0, 0, 0), Percent_White_Students = c(0, 0, 0, 0.00539568345323741, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0023696682464455), Percent_White_Teachers = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

##Section 2 ____________________________________________________
#set up the user interface
ui = shinyUI(
  fluidPage( #allows layout to fill browser window
    titlePanel("Why does the error flash and then go away?"),
    sidebarPanel( #designates location of following items
      htmlOutput("school_selector")
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot1") #put plot item in main area

      # Output: HTML table with requested number of observations ----
      # tableOutput("view")

    )
  ) )


##Section 3 ____________________________________________________
#server controls what is displayed by the user interface
server = shinyServer(function(input, output) {


  output$school_selector = renderUI({#creates County select box object called in ui

    data_available <- schools
    #creates a reactive list of available x based on the y selection made

    selectInput(inputId = "school", #name of input
                label = "School:", #label displayed in ui
                choices = unique(data_available), #calls list of available counties
                selected = "Madison At Chancellor South")
  })


  output$plot1 = renderPlot({ #creates a the plot to go in the mainPanel

    # add validate here 
    validate(
      need(input$school != "", "No school selected") # display custom message in need
    )

    focal.school <- schools %>% filter(school_name == input$school)

    ggplot(focal.school, aes(x=input$school, y=Percent_Black_Students)) +
      geom_point()
  })

})#close the shinyServer


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It is good practice to always include necessary `validate()` statements in your shiny code.

Comment: Thanks, that's better. But now, "No school selected" pops up for a short period of time. I thought giving a `selected` value within `selectInput` would prevent this. However, the renderUI() doesn't seem to evaluate before the renderPlot.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment! I see what you did. I just changed your "No school selected" to blank (""), so that it looks relatively seamless. It would be cool if I could display the "No school selected" message for just a few seconds, but Sys.sleep(3) isn't the best approach. Hmm.

Comment: So you want to display "No school selected" or not?

Comment: I would only display "No school selected" if I could do it for a specific number of seconds.